# Inserting XML file into MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, xml, database, jdbc

Good afternoon, Java beginner here and I have been working with this tutorial online and the tutorial supplied this code along with an XML file. It said that it was based off of inserting the XML file into MySQL but doesn't auto insert the fields. So what I have done is created a database named movie, and have created a table named 'about'. So coming from the XML there are 4 field names. I've tried creating the 4 fields inside of that table but I end up getting the error:

```
Field:year
Field:title
Field:movieid
Field:unsortabletitle
INSERT INTO about VALUES (?,?,?,?)
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'The Godfather' for column 'year' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1494)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.startElement(Inserter.java:138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.run(Inserter.java:60)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.main(Inserter.java:87)
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'The Shawshank Redemption' for column 'year' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1347)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:958)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1494)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.startElement(Inserter.java:138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.run(Inserter.java:60)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.main(Inserter.java:87)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.run(Inserter.java:63)
    at xSQLTEST.Inserter.main(Inserter.java:87)
```

Any Information at this point would be very helpful. I have tried researching the error, and I couldn't find much information on it. If anyone is willing to run this and help me set up MySql table correctly I would greatly appreciate it.
    package xSQLTEST;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Inserter extends DefaultHandler {

        HashMap fieldnames = new HashMap();
        HashMap values = new HashMap();
        String tableName = "movie";
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        static final   String       sNEWLINE   = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
        static private Writer       out        = null;
        private        StringBuffer textBuffer = null;
        int     numErrors = 0;
        long numInserts = 0;


        public void run(String [] args) {
                SAXParser saxParser;


                tableName = "about";
                String file = "C:\\insertxml.xml";


                try {
                        try {
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                                System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
                                System.out.println("Let's print a stack trace, and exit.");
                                cnfe.printStackTrace();
                                System.exit(1);
                        }

                        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movies",
                                        "root", "Password!");
                        saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
                        long timePre = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        saxParser.parse( new File( file ), this );
                        long timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long timeTaken = (timeAfter - timePre)/1000;
                        long insertsPerSecond = numInserts/timeTaken;
                        System.out.println("Errors: " + numErrors);
                        System.out.println("Inserts: " + numInserts);
                        System.out.println("Inserts per second: " + insertsPerSecond);
                        System.out.println("Seconds taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timePre)/1000);


                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
                new Inserter().run(args);

        }

//      ---- SAX DefaultHandler methods ----

        public void startDocument()
        throws SAXException
        {
                //echoString( sNEWLINE + "<?xml ...?>" + sNEWLINE + sNEWLINE );
        }

        public void endDocument()
        throws SAXException
        {
                echoString( sNEWLINE );
        }

        public void startElement( String namespaceURI,
                        String localName,   // local name
                        String qName,       // qualified name
                        Attributes attrs )  throws SAXException {
                echoTextBuffer();
                String eName = ( "".equals( localName ) ) ? qName : localName;

                if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIELD")) {
                        fieldnames.put(attrs.getValue("FieldName"), attrs.getValue("FieldType"));
                        System.out.println("Field:" + attrs.getValue("FieldName"));
                } else if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("ROW")) {
                        try {
                                // for each field prepare statement
                                Iterator itFields = fieldnames.keySet().iterator();
                                int fieldIdx = 1;
                                while(itFields.hasNext()) {
                                        String fieldName = itFields.next().toString();
                                        String type = fieldnames.get(fieldName).toString();
                                        String value = attrs.getValue(fieldName);

                                        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Integer")) {
                                                try {
                                                        ps.setInt(fieldIdx, Integer.parseInt(value));
                                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                        numErrors++;
                                                }
                                        } else {
                                                ps.setString(fieldIdx, value);
                                        }
                                        fieldIdx++;
                                } // end while

                                ps.execute();
                                if(numInserts % 50000 == 0) {
                                        System.out.println(numInserts + " inserts made.");
                                }
                                numInserts++;

                                ps.clearParameters();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                                numErrors++;
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

        }

        public void endElement( String namespaceURI,
                        String localName,     // local name
                        String qName )        // qualified name
        throws SAXException
        {

                String eName = ( "".equals( localName ) ) ? qName : localName;
                if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("METADATA")) {
                        // build sql
                        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                        for(int i = 0; i < fieldnames.size(); i++) {
                                buf.append("?");
                                if(i < (fieldnames.size()-1)) {
                                        buf.append(",");
                                }
                        }


                        try {
                                ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + buf.toString() + ")");
                                System.out.println("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + buf.toString() + ")");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }


//              echoTextBuffer();

//              echoString( "</" + eName + ">" );           // element name
        }

        public void characters( char[] buf, int offset, int len )
        throws SAXException
        {
//              String s = new String( buf, offset, len );
//              if( textBuffer == null )
//              textBuffer = new StringBuffer( s );
//              else
//              textBuffer.append( s );
        }

        // ---- Helper methods ----

        // Display text accumulated in the character buffer
        private void echoTextBuffer()
        throws SAXException
        {
                if( textBuffer == null )  return;
                echoString( textBuffer.toString() );
                textBuffer = null;
        }

        // Wrap I/O exceptions in SAX exceptions, to
        // suit handler signature requirements
        private void echoString( String s )
        throws SAXException
        {
                try {
                        if( null == out )
                                out = new OutputStreamWriter( System.out, "UTF8" );
                        out.write( s );
                        out.flush();
                } catch( IOException ex ) {
                        throw new SAXException( "I/O error", ex );
                }
        }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="no"?>
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
        <METADATA>
                <FIELDS>
                        <FIELD FieldName="year" DisplayLabel="year" FieldType="Integer" FieldClass="TField"/>
                        <FIELD FieldName="title" DisplayLabel="title" FieldType="String" FieldClass="TField"/>
                        <FIELD FieldName="movieid" DisplayLabel="movieid" FieldType="String" FieldClass="TField"/>
                        <FIELD FieldName="unsortabletitle" DisplayLabel="unsortabletitle" FieldType="String" FieldClass="TField"/>
                </FIELDS>
        </METADATA>
        <ROWDATA>
                <ROW year="1972" title="Godfather, The" movieid="A0AD59890237CBC738B3EDE134846225" unsortabletitle="The Godfather"/>
                <ROW year="1994" title="Shawshank Redemption, The" movieid="569150D16B224C8A5E2E3D320FC0A6CA" unsortabletitle="The Shawshank Redemption"/>
        </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

How I set it up in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE about
(
year int,
title varchar(255),
movieid varchat(255),
unsortabletitle varchar(255)
);
```

Comment: Could you post your table that you are writing to? :) Thank you!

Comment: :) Could you edit it into your question?

Comment: @JosefE. Sorry about that, I just added it.

Comment: I found the tutorial you are using :P

Comment: If it's of any use, an alternative approach can be seen here for MySql 5.5+. This leaves the parsing of the XML to MySQL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the cause of the problem.

Look in this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Test extends DefaultHandler {

        HashMap fieldnames = new HashMap();
        HashMap values = new HashMap();
        String tableName = "movie";
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        static final   String       sNEWLINE   = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
        static private Writer       out        = null;
        private        StringBuffer textBuffer = null;
        int     numErrors = 0;
        long numInserts = 0;


        public void run(String [] args) {
                SAXParser saxParser;


                tableName = "about";
                String file = "C:\\insertxml.xml";


                try {
                        saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
                        long timePre = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        saxParser.parse( new File( file ), this );
                        long timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long timeTaken = (timeAfter - timePre)/1000;
                        long insertsPerSecond = numInserts/timeTaken; // <---- Error if timeTaken is zero
                        System.out.println("Errors: " + numErrors);
                        System.out.println("Inserts: " + numInserts);
                        System.out.println("Inserts per second: " + insertsPerSecond);
                        System.out.println("Seconds taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - timePre)/1000);


                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
                new Test().run(args);

        }

//      ---- SAX DefaultHandler methods ----

        public void startDocument()
        throws SAXException
        {
                //echoString( sNEWLINE + "<?xml ...?>" + sNEWLINE + sNEWLINE );
        }

        public void endDocument()
        throws SAXException
        {
                echoString( sNEWLINE );
        }

        public void startElement( String namespaceURI,
                        String localName,   // local name
                        String qName,       // qualified name
                        Attributes attrs )  throws SAXException {
                echoTextBuffer();
                String eName = ( "".equals( localName ) ) ? qName : localName;

                if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIELD")) {
                        fieldnames.put(attrs.getValue("FieldName"), attrs.getValue("FieldType"));
                        System.out.println("Field:" + attrs.getValue("FieldName"));
                } else if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("ROW")) {
                                // for each field prepare statement
                                Iterator itFields = fieldnames.keySet().iterator();
                                int fieldIdx = 1;
                                while(itFields.hasNext()) {
                                        String fieldName = itFields.next().toString();
                                        String type = fieldnames.get(fieldName).toString();
                                        String value = attrs.getValue(fieldName);

                                        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Integer")) {
                                            System.out.println(fieldIdx+" (integer) value:"+value);
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println(fieldIdx+" (string) value:"+value);
                                        }
                                        fieldIdx++;
                                } // end while
                }

        }

        public void endElement( String namespaceURI,
                        String localName,     // local name
                        String qName )        // qualified name
        throws SAXException
        {

                String eName = ( "".equals( localName ) ) ? qName : localName;
                if(eName.equalsIgnoreCase("METADATA")) {
                        // build sql
                        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                        for(int i = 0; i < fieldnames.size(); i++) {
                                buf.append("?");
                                if(i < (fieldnames.size()-1)) {
                                        buf.append(",");
                                }
                        }


//                        try {
//                                ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + buf.toString() + ")");
//                                System.out.println("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (" + buf.toString() + ")");
//                        } catch (SQLException e) {
//                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                                e.printStackTrace();
//                        }

                }


//              echoTextBuffer();

//              echoString( "</" + eName + ">" );           // element name
        }

        public void characters( char[] buf, int offset, int len )
        throws SAXException
        {
//              String s = new String( buf, offset, len );
//              if( textBuffer == null )
//              textBuffer = new StringBuffer( s );
//              else
//              textBuffer.append( s );
        }

        // ---- Helper methods ----

        // Display text accumulated in the character buffer
        private void echoTextBuffer()
        throws SAXException
        {
                if( textBuffer == null )  return;
                echoString( textBuffer.toString() );
                textBuffer = null;
        }

        // Wrap I/O exceptions in SAX exceptions, to
        // suit handler signature requirements
        private void echoString( String s )
        throws SAXException
        {
                try {
                        if( null == out )
                                out = new OutputStreamWriter( System.out, "UTF8" );
                        out.write( s );
                        out.flush();
                } catch( IOException ex ) {
                        throw new SAXException( "I/O error", ex );
                }
        }
}
```

The output of it is:

```
    Field:year
    Field:title
    Field:movieid
    Field:unsortabletitle
    1 (string) value:The Godfather
    2 (string) value:Godfather, The
    3 (integer) value:1972
    4 (string) value:A0AD59890237CBC738B3EDE134846225
    1 (string) value:The Shawshank Redemption
    2 (string) value:Shawshank Redemption, The
    3 (integer) value:1994
    4 (string) value:569150D16B224C8A5E2E3D320FC0A6CA

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at Test.run(Test.java:49)
        at Test.main(Test.java:70)
```

That is because your code is assuming the XML will be read in the same order it was written, which is not the case. The attributes in XML don't have a established order. So the first item doesn't necessarily has to be the year, so when you parse it, you get the exception.

To fix your code, use the field name to determine the location in the table and don't trust that the first attribute will be the year, the second will be the title, etc.

Comment: how did you insert your table/fields into MySQL? MySQL doesn't support string imports right? EX: Title String, Movieid String

Comment: I didn't. I removed any code that would update MySQL to isolate the issue.

Comment: did you mean in terms of fix mXML file or in terms of my Java file?

Comment: in your Java file. There's nothing you can do in the XML file.